# Adding persistence to react redux immutable web app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, persistence, immutability, immutable.js

I am trying to add persistence to my redux stores, I am using Immutable.js within my webapp. I have seen the following libraries: https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist and https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist-immutable I am wondering exactly how to create the persister and the store in context of my application, please see the following `config-store.js`:

```
import rootReducer from '../reducers'
import {
  createStore,
  compose,
  applyMiddleware
} from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

export default (initialState) => {
  return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(thunk),
      window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
    )
  );
};
```

and my `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './store/configure-store';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

const store = configureStore();

render(
   <Provider store={store}>
     <App />
   </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: What functionality are you looking for? Just to have your store available offline?

Comment: Yes, and then rehydrated back in when refreshed

Answer (score 0):

Load the persiting state from local storage.

```
if (localStorage.getItem("state")) {
  var serializedState = localStorage.getItem("state");
  /* upload changes to server here */
  preloadedState = JSON.parse(serializedState);
}
```

Save store changes to local storage.

```
store.subscribe(() => {
  var serializedState = JSON.stringify(store.getState());
  localStorage.setItem("state", serializedState);
});
```

Comment: where exactly should this go...?

Comment: So, this works as expected for storing the state in local storage, however I am unsure where to load the state back in?

Comment: The first code block of this answer is the loading from local storage. The preloadedState is the initialState variable in the code you posted.

Comment: I don't really understand to be honest where this should go in relation to my code base. Please see code pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bLMgpv?editors=0010 I'm not sure if this is correct, but I assume not because I receive the following error: `Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined`

Comment: So, I got this to work, sort of. However it seems like the immutable state is not preserved as `.get` is now undefined.